# transparent background-color WP

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress template. I need my menubar to be transparent, but it is giving me quite a hard time.

Until now I added the following css code in the "Custom CSS". But I keep getting a grey colored background. Does anybody knows how I can make a transparent background in the CSS?

```
.fixed-header #header {
  background-color: rgba(1,1,1,0.0) !important;
}
.fixed-header #header {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Please include a link to the site so that we can see where the grey background is coming from,... only then will we be able to tell you how to change it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
 .fixed-header #header {
             background-color: rgba(1,1,1,0.0) !important;
             opacity: 0.5 !important; 
             background-color: transparent !important; 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add style in your style.css file

```
#header {
   background-color: rgba(1,1,1,0.0) !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggenstion. I just tried to add the css, but no transparency or color is changing.

Comment: Have you try only with backgound property instead of background-color property. i think it's work.

Answer (score 0):

[Install this plugin for including custom css and js](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/)

Try this:

`.fixed-header #header {
    background-color: transparent;
}`

You might be editing wrong css file. Or your website is cached. Try pressing CTRL + F5 to refresh page.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried what you suggested, but still no result. I also tried in the developer window without any result.

Comment: Just install that plugin, it's really helpfull, and press Add CSS code.

Comment: The same thing you can do online on the page, where you can add "Custom CSS". So no reason for installing a plugin for that. I can easily make the background-color etc. So it is the correct CSS file. 

THe funny thing is when you start scrolling down on the page, the menubar turn into transparent.