# Transparent header background

Tags: css, wordpress

I am struggeling with a problem in my header. At the moment the header have a grey background. When you scroll down the header turns transparent:

[Link to website][1]

That so be opposite. The menu should be transparent when the page is all the way up, and get a white background-color when you start scrolling down the page.

I have a feeling that it is something with the `.fixed-header #header` class. I tried to add the following codem, but that makes the text transparent, and not the background.

```
/* Menubar background */
.fixed-header #header {
    background-color: rgba(1,1,1,0.0) !important;
    opacity: 0.5 !important; 
    background-color: transparent !important; 
      }
```

Can anybody help me solve this problem?

Comment: Both of the `background-color` give the transparent effect, so why did you use both?

Comment: look for your theme settings you'll find how to change this

Comment: Duplicate of your own question you asked just yesterday: [transparent background-color WP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956868/transparent-background-color-wp) Please don’t do that. If you have information to add, edit your original question, instead of creating a duplicate.

Comment: @CBroe: sorry about that. It seemed to answer the question the other day. After I cleared the cache in wordpress, it suddenly did not work.

Comment: Wow, using important all over the place, your code will be a nightmare!  I think you should learn to do css properly before continuing down this path

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jquery for this. When the menu is at the top of the page, it can have a default white color or whatever you wish, but then when you start scrolling down you can tell it to change the `background-color` to transparent.

See the example below.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 500) {
    $(".menu").addClass("transparent");
  } else {
    $(".menu").removeClass("transparent");
  }
});
```

```css
.menu {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 200;
  width: 100%;
}

.transparent {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="menu"></header>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
.fixed-header #header {
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

EDIT: you should try jquery:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){

        if($(window).scrollTop() == 0){

        $(".fixed-header #header").css("background-color", "transparent");

        }

        else if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0){

        $(".fixed-header #header").css("background-color", "white");

        }

    });
```

I hope it helps, Regards.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just tried to add the code. It does not give me any result unfortunately :-(

Comment: try jquery to change the color on scroll bro, the css is fine!.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.97);
```

from

```
.fixed-header #header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.97);
    z-index: 500;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

Comment: Hello Sheedo. I just tried your suggestion in Developer tools. Nothing is changing with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/* Menubar background */
.fixed-header #header {
background-color: rgba(1,1,1,0.0) !important; // remove this css
opacity: 0.5 !important; 
  }
```